# Using Function<I,O> Readability and Performance

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-7

In the beginning, given a list of objects, before I can use that provided list, I have to do some filterings to the list. So naturally, I do as following:

```
List<Pokemon> pokemons = ....;
// {A block of code} : Reverse the list
// {A block of code} : Limit the list to N number
// {A block of code} : Only keep pokemons that ....
```

Then I see how Guava FluentIterable works. So I start trying to do what FluentIterable does.

I make a new class, call it PokemonsBuilder

```
    class PokemonsBuilder{
      List<Pokemons> result;
      public static newBuilder(){result = new List..};
      public PokemonsBuilder from (List<Pokemons> input){result.addAll(input) ; return this};
      public PokemonsBuilder apply(Function<List<Pokemons>,List<Pokemons>> filter){ result = filter.apply(result) ; return this};
      public List<Pokemons> build(){return result};
    }
```

And another class, call it PokemonsBuildOptions

```
     class PokemonsBuildOptions{
       public final Function<List<Pokemons>,List<Pokemons>> REVERSE_OPTION(){ return new Function ....}
       public final Function<List<Pokemons>,List<Pokemons>> LIMIT_OPTION(int limitTo){ return new Function ....}
       public final Function<List<Pokemons>,List<Pokemons>> ABC_OPTION(){ return new Function ....}
}
```

So now my code changes from

```
List<Pokemon> pokemons = ....;
// {A block of code} : Reverse the list
// {A block of code} : Limit the list to N number
// {A block of code} : Only keep pokemons that ....
```

to

```
   List<Pokemons> filteredList = PokemonsBuilder.newBuilder()
    .from(pokemons)
    .apply(PokemonsBuildOptions.REVERSE_OPTION)
    .apply(PokemonsBuildOptions.LIMIT_OPTION)
    .apply(PokemonsBuildOptions.ABC_OPTION)
    .apply(..Some other options for future usage..)
    .build();
```

Up to this point, my feeling is divided into 02 different ways:

1. I love the new code, it makes things become easier to understand (at least to me)
2. I notice the increment in the number of lines of code. Then I start wondering:

   - Will this way of coding slow down the performance of my application?
   - Am I over complicating my code by abusing the usage of Function?

I'm a junior eng. Thus any comment or recommendation are more than welcomed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The factory is frequently used for these types of situations. I don't think your code is getting more complicated, on the contrary, you're simplifying a lot of tasks.

Comment: No, this is absolutely complicating the code uselessly.  You're wrapping a method into a function and then applying the function, instead of just applying the method directly.  What's the point?  Guava's documentation advises against code like this.  Just use the methods directly.

Comment: Also, if you're using Java 8 like your code is tagged, why aren't you using lambdas and streams?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I haven't noticed that java-8 is tagged. My code actually is java 7

Comment: @LouisWasserman good question. one point I don't understand is that, why  Guava's documentation against this type of coding , while they still provide somethings like FluentIterable ("Anything which can be done using FluentIterable could be done in a different fashion (often with Iterables), however the use of FluentIterable makes many sets of operations significantly more concise.")

Comment: @Xitrum it can improve things when used carefully in moderation, but the way you're using it here doesn't actually simplify anything relative to writing the code directly.

Comment: You can achieve most of this by leveraging more of Guava's classes rather than re-writing and re-wrapping everything. On the performance side, there are simply not enough Pokemons for this to matter at all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman My only argument will be, I can have a better overview of what is happening on my original list. And I can clearly see what will happen to the list when the order of options, or different sets of options is applied. Maybe I'm wrong, but then FluentIterable also doesn't make sense to me anymore, since I can do as you say, just write the code directly. Or perhaps I don't know how much careful in moderation I should consider.

Comment: @pvg You are correct in the point that Guava supports most of the things. But there will be more things, which are not be supported in my case. Then the question is, so instead of mixing up between guava and my own code to archive what I need, why can I just make something that I can use from top to toe :) ?

Comment: @Xitrum A major difference between `FluentIterable` and what you have is that it supports methods like `.limit(n)` instead of taking some `Function` that does limiting for it; if you do anything along these lines, you should be doing something like that.  That said, it's not at all clear to me in what sense this is a "better overview."  Do you just mean that it's in another order?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I mean for the readability. Since I can quickly follow what is happening. You are right about the other way also, but then I think it depends on which way people want to read the code. To me, A.toB.toC.toD is easier to read than B = toBfromA(A); C = toCfromB(B); D = toDFromC(C) ...

Comment: If you're going to do it like that, then build the methods into `PokemonBuilder` like `.reverse().limit(50)` etc. instead of trying to wrap them up into `Function` objects.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think that is the answer I may looking for. So I will extend my builder with general methods such as reverse, limit ... and keeps the apply(Function<I,O>) for more specific actions that I want to perform. Perhap can you make it as your answer below ?

Comment: @Xitrum mostly because you're more likely to make a mess of it, not that it should stop or discourage you from trying. I think your initial instinct of just programming this directly was right. If you do find yourself having to slice and dice your pokemons in 17 different ways, you're better off using Guava, switching to Java 8 or even throwing these into a (possibly embedded) SQL db which turns all of this stuff into readable one-liners.

Comment: Where fluentIterable really comes in handy is replacing code that performs multiple filters and transformations on a collection, in the end iterating over the same data multiple times to finally arrive at a set of data in the form you need.  fluentIterable takes a different tack, setting up a pipeline of transformations, sorts, filters, etc., and then running the data through the pipeline only once.  It can significantly reduce processing time in that manner.